# Xubuntu 15.04 Cannot Suspend when inactive

Tags: xfce4-power-manager

I have Xubuntu 15.04 installed and having some issues with Suspend. It Suspends fine when done from the command line or the shutdown menu or even by closing the lid. I have set the inactivity timer to 15 minutes using xfce power manager for suspend. However, it never suspends because of inactivity. When I log back in after the failure to suspend, I see this message on the top right:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied

I have tried some of the solutions online such as the ones [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1441460) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180798) but it didn't make a difference.

Anyone has any ideas of things to try. Is there any logs that can tell me what could be wrong.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like your user is not allowed to suspend the PC when not logged in.

Open `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy`
with your favorite editor as root and search for entry
`<action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend">`

Change
`<allow_inactive>auth_admin_keep</allow_inactive>`
to :
`<allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>`

Comment: I required both the change to polkit described in this answer and the change to inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery for suspend to work on Xubuntu 16.04.3

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue in Xubuntu 16.04, this fixed it for me:

At the terminal, type:

`xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -lv`

If the output of the above command doesn't contain the following line:

```
/xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery   1
```

then, at the terminal type:

`xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery -n -t int -s 1`

Comment: Well, I wanted to try this advice, but it did nothing. No output followed. Perhaps because I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, not Xubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes, this solution relates to XFCE, so would be of no use in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately neither of the other answers by AlexAndersan and Holy Mackerel helped, and this is still an issue in Jammy. My error message was a bit different though: it spoke of a failure rather than a denied access. From what I understand screen locking relies on `gnome-screensaver`, which is surprising: I'd expect `xflock4` to handle this.

To check whether this can solve your problem, run `gnome-screensaver` in a terminal, then try suspending your system again. If it works, make the changes permanent by instructing XFCE to launch `gnome-screensaver` on login (go to Settings -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart, then add the program, log out, and log back in again). "Launch[ing] GNOME services on startup" doesn't cut it.