# gdbus.error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied error when running on battery

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, battery, policykit

I have ASUS GL552VW laptop with Xubuntu 17.04 and when I get out of power (running on battery) I've got this error in notification popup:

```
gdbus.error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied Permission denied
```

I've found this [DBus Permission denied when suspend/hibernate](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180798) but I don't know what rule should I add and in which file.

Comment: I had the same problem on my eee pc 1000HG. I think i've fixed it by following the suggestions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/627356/xubuntu-15-04-cannot-suspend-when-inactive/851760#851760 Specifically, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/851760) worked for me.

Comment: **Close vote Review queue reviewers:** Please close Non-repro as per comment from OP to answer.